# Can the order of list fields retrieved by REST be changed?

Tags: 2013, list, rest

Is there any way to change the order of the fields associated with a list in SharePoint?

Ie. the fields retrieved with a url like this:

```
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListTitle')/fields
```

I know that it is possible to change the order of fields associated with a content type, but all the fields associated with a list aren't included in the content type.

Most importantly the Created By and Modified By fields are not included in the content type and it does not look like it's possible to add them to a content type.

Comment: Do you want to sort the results based on the field name? You can use a $orderby in that case.

Comment: I would like to have a way for the order the fields are returned in by the REST call to change based on an order the end user sets so I don't think $orderby would be that helpful.  This is very simple for the fields associated with a content type but unless there is a way to add Created By and Modified By fields to a content type this won't really work for me.

Comment: You could create a custom view and make a REST call to get that view fields

Comment: That could work but I only get the internal names of the fields and no other information.  I think the best solution is for me to add the Created By and Modified By columns to a content type, I should probably post another question asking about that.